# User-specific settings for microservice

Tags: architecture, microservices

Lets say there is this **service A**, that's in charge of selling apples to the users.

If every user had to pay a different price for an apple, would this data (setting) be stored as a part of the **service A** database, or should it be external?

If we had more than one different configs ( user/apple cost, user/apple discount, user/apple allowance), what would be a good architectural approach to deal with User/Service mappings, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Depends upon complexity. I've seen such a complicated microservice topology that separated `ConfigurationService` was perfectly reasonable decision. As long as your domain simple enough, such a setting definitely belongs to the service `A`.

Keep in mind that once upon a time this setting might be required somewhere else, so write such code, that would allow you to cut it out and publish as separated package/self-hosted service **easily**.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is to store this relation in service A microservice because the price is information that is directly related to the selling process, and not something inherent to the user.
So I would have a table or any other store mechanism in wich I relate users and the price they have for every item. For example in a relational way I would have a table with (productId, userId, price)

Comment: That's actually what i have at the moment, I was just wondering if there is a better approach, since by adding a lot more of the settings like in the example below, we'd drastically increase the size of the service as well as the HTTP traffic.

Comment: If the price can be different by user and product and there isn't a rule that can be apply to obtain the value. You have to store all the information in one or other way. If this combination is very large the only solution I think is to have a service by product with the mappings per user for that product that could scale independtly from others

Comment: This way you'd potentially end-up with a very large number of services, not sure how commercially viable that is.

Comment: You are right, I think the better approach is the first solution metioned with a sharded  databse by UserId so the traffic will be splitted among multiple instances and as long as all users would have the same records it will be balanced. Respect to the amount of http traffic, I think this is independent of the way you store the data or the amount of microservices you have. The solution will be using a cache if the prices are not very volatile

Answer (score -1):

It completely depends on how your business logic runs. Micro-service is just a way of accessing the business rule.
Assuming that you have two kinds of rules:
1. RP1: Product Specific Rules For all parmeters (Rules for apples, mangoes,oranges etc)
This ruleset can probably be table that is a lookup for a base value of a product:

[image: Product Base Values]

2. RU1: User specific Rules (Premium users, General users etc). Another lookup based on USerID or User Segment

[image: User Rules]]

I would try to define my calculation in a way that RP1 and RU1 can be calculated independently and then combined. 
So my final micro-service **Service A**  would have
(Input:Product,User, Parameter_list; Output: parameter_value_list).
Service A should internally call RP1 and RU1 and combine the outputs, using a third set of rules.
This rule could be a static rule that returns 
Price of apple on Monday for Premium Customer=1*0.9

OR another lookup like on combination of base value and param:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can use map the data for each country with ConfigurationProperties.

Example code:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("a")
public class customConfiguration{

    private final Map<String, String> b= new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, String> getB() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

And in your properties file:

```
a.b.c = 5
a.b.d = 10
```

when you implement it, you have a map

```
b = {c->5, d->10}
```